# Why are docker layer IDs now hidden with the new storage model?

Tags: docker

Docker 1.10 introduced a new [content adressable storage model](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#content-addressable-storage). So now a layer ID is created as a hash from its content. This way layers with the same content should be reused.

This sounds nice, but why the heck is this ID hidden from us now? I've done some simple tests to find out, if layers are really reused. For example I've tried to do some automated builds from the same source but with different tags.

I still end up with different image IDs in the end. And if I look at `docker history` I only get `<missing>` for image IDs:

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
7b007b10103a        15 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:4c2cb4c2780edc6e2   37.77 kB            
<missing>           15 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:ac11867f64e4fdd4e   856 B               
<missing>           15 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) ENV PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/u   0 B                 
<missing>           15 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) MAINTAINER haertl.mike@gmai   0 B
```

Why is this information hidden now? And why do images with the same content still have different Image IDs?

EDIT: There's even a note in the docker documentation about this. But this does not explain *why* this decision has been made. IMO it takes away a lot of transparency from docker images and makes them harder to analyse/debug.

From their [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/#content-addressable-storage):

> Note: Under the content addressable storage model introduced with Docker 1.10, image history data is no longer stored in a config file with each image layer. It is now stored as a string of text in a single config file that relates to the overall image. This can result in some image layers showing as “missing” in the output of the docker history command. This is normal behaviour and can be ignored.
>
> You may hear images like these referred to as flat images.

Comment: I can only speculate as I didn't follow the project for a while, But COPY/ENV/MAINTAINER are "fake" layers that don't require a full blow ID. For steps matter, it is displayed, but I think under the hood, it is a single layer.

Comment: Could you build a couple of containers with some `RUN apt-get ..` and post the result history please. This may confirm @creack sayings.

Comment: @creack No, that's not the problem. They even mention it in their documentation. I've updated the question.

Comment: I hope this post will answer on all of your questions http://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/

Comment: @RafaelSeidalinov It's a good summary, thanks. It also agrees, that the `IMAGE` column now is quite "*misleading and a little unfortunate*". Guess, we have to live with it.